# Neural network package for strategy and games

Tags: neural-network

I would like to use neural network method for approximating Nash Equilibrium for general games (especially card games)... What would be some standard package I could use? Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear.  In which language do you want the package/library?

Comment: anything.... python or c++

Comment: Cross-posted: http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/6356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be looking into [Gambit](http://www.gambit-project.org/) which is a GNU licensed package for exactly that sort of thing:

- Open Source - GNU GPL Licence
- Cross Platform Windows, Mac & Linux
- GUI for exploring strategies & outcomes
- [Python](http://python.org) API for implementing complex games, etc.
- Command-line tools

  - gambit-enumpure: Enumerate pure-strategy equilibria of a game
  - gambit-enumpoly: Compute equilibria of a game using polynomial systems of equations
  - gambit-enummixed: Enumerate equilibria in a two-player game
  - gambit-gnm: Compute **Nash equilibria** in a strategic game using a global Newton method
  - gambit-ipa: Compute **Nash equilibria** in a strategic game using iterated polymatrix approximation
  - gambit-lcp: Compute equilibria in a two-player game via linear complementarity
  - gambit-lp: Compute equilibria in a two-player constant-sum game via linear programming
  - gambit-liap: Compute **Nash equilibria** using function minimization
  - gambit-simpdiv: Compute equilibria via simplicial subdivision
  - gambit-logit: Compute quantal response equilbria
  - gambit-convert: Convert games among various representations

Comment: the problem is, the game I am interested in is extremely complex, just like texas holdem... Which i think those method should not work...

Comment: Have you tried it costs nothing